# How to sent form data param in plugin-file-transfer in ionic3?

Tags: ionic3

I am trying to upload an image on ionic3 and I am using @ionic-native/file-transfer and

```js
public uploadImage() {
  // Destination URL
  var url = "https://linker.co.in/auth/update_profile_image";
 
  // File for Upload
  var targetPath = this.pathForImage(this.lastImage);
  // File name only
  var filename = this.lastImage;

   //
  var clientConfirmData = new FormData();
  clientConfirmData.append('image', filename);

    var options = {
      fileKey: "file",
       chunkedMode: false,
      fileName: this.lastImage,
      mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
       headers: {'userid' :  this.userObject.user_id},
      params : clientConfirmData
    };
 
    const fileTransfer : FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
  
  // Use the FileTransfer to upload the image
  fileTransfer.upload(targetPath, url, options).then(data => {
      let response = data.response;
      var r = JSON.parse(response);

      if(r.status) { 
        this.selectedImage = r;
        this.userObject.image = r.image;
      } 

    this.presentToast('Image succesful uploaded');
  }, err => {
    console.log('ddd' +err);
    this.presentToast('Error while uploading file.');
  });
}
```

i have sent image param in the formData and i am using the below format :

> var clientConfirmData = new FormData();
>     clientConfirmData.append('image', filename);

but it's not working I got every time response null from Backend.please tell me, anyone, how to sent the param in the formData I have tried above format but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

file transfer is deprecated I had no luck in getting it to work. I used angular httpclient in my ionic project so it's something like this

```
let options = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
body = {
'image': filename
}
this.http.post("https://ams.consagous.co.in/auth/update_profile_image",
 body, {
  headers: options
}).subscribe(response => { 
  return console.log('response');
});
```

Comment: ok sir i agree with you but i have to open the gallery option like upload image from gallary.so tell me sir which plugin we have to use for upload image as well as how to sent param in formData?